# How to get user-selected date format in Android?

Tags: android, datetime, format, locale

I have been working on problem of date format selected by users in the Android Phone.
I have gone through almost many question and answers on the stackoverlow and havent got the perfect answer.
For example:-
I have selected dateformat in phone is "Sat, 31 Dec 2011"
But when I used as based question answered on stackoverflow:-

```
DateFormat df = android.text.format.DateFormat.getDateFormat(context.getApplicationContext());
tv.setText(df.format(date));
```

Above code returns me 06/08/2011 (mm/dd/yyyy) format.
But see the date format i selected on phone. How can i get the exact format?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In an application I'm currently developing I use the following, which I believe will do what you require

```
final String format = Settings.System.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.DATE_FORMAT);
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(format)) {
  dateFormat = android.text.format.DateFormat.getMediumDateFormat(getApplicationContext());
} else {
  dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
}
```

Comment: what is the library for this Settings?

Answer (score 4):

The `DateFormat.getDateFormat` works as expected. It returns one of three possible formats:

1. `MM/DD/YYYY`
2. `DD/MM/YYYY`
3. `YYYY/MM/DD`

I'm not sure how you set your *"Sat, 31 Dec 2011"* format, but as far as I know stock Android allows to set only one of three mentioned formats (Settings -> Date and Time -> Select Date Format).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
Date inDate = inFormat.parse(in);
DateFormat outFormat = android.text.format.DateFormat.getDateFormat(context);
out=outFormat.format(inDate);
```