# How to set the Value of EditText as like 1:00 PM or 8:00 AM?

Tags: android, datetime, android-layout, android-ndk, timepicker

I am using this code to get the time from the Time Picker. . .

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
        case TIME_DIALOG_ID:
            return new TimePickerDialog(this,mTimeSetListener, Calendar.HOUR, Calendar.MINUTE, false);
    }
    return null;
}

private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            reminderSetTime.setText(""+hourOfDay+":"+minute+"");
            Toast.makeText(ImportantDateReminderActivity.this, "Time is="+hourOfDay+":"+minute, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };

static final int TIME_DIALOG_ID = 0;
```

And to Display the TimePicker i use below code:

```
    case R.id.reminderTime:
            showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID);
            break;
```

With doing that i am not getting the proper value of the time.
I want the Value like 1:00 PM and 10:00 AM 
But i am not getting PM/AM and if the time is more then 12 then i am getting 13,14. . .  like figure. instead of that i want the figure in 1 to 12.

So how to set that value ??
Thanks.

Comment: It's strange cause you have the is24HourView to false. Any log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            mHour = hourOfDay;
            mMinute = minute;
            if(mHour==12)
                btnFromTime.setText(new StringBuilder().append("12").append(":").append(pad(minute)+" PM"));
        else
            updateTimeDisplay();
        }
    };
```

this is working for me...

and use this

```
private void updateTimeDisplay() {

        try {
            Format formatter;
            SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
            Date d = df.parse(mHour + ":" + mMinute);
            Calendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
            gc.setTime(d);
            gc.add(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
            Date d2 = gc.getTime();
            formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
            String time = formatter.format(d2);

            btnFromTime.setText(time);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: What is "pad" beforeminute object ? I am not getting it.

Comment: public  String pad(int c) {
  if (c >= 10)
   return String.valueOf(c);
  else
   return "0" + String.valueOf(c);
  
 }

Answer (score 1):

Did you try: `TimePicker.setIs24HourView(false)` ?

Answer (score 1):

It's Androids best practice to do whatever the user wants; what is set in the Android settings:

[How to get user-selected date format in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6981505/android-get-user-selected-date-format)

Check TIME_12_24

Answer to you question, you can use the DateFormat class to achive what you want