# How to change simpledateformat according to device/local timezone

Tags: android, timezone, simpledateformat

My code:

```
SimpleDateFormat today= new SimpleDateFormat("E, MMM dd, yyyy");
 TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();
 today.setTimeZone(tz);
 dt = today.format(c.getTimeInMillis());
 time.setText("Today "+dt);
```

My default date format is Mon, May 05, 2014

if i change my settings in device to format: 2014/12/31
then i should get my date in that format like Mon, 2014, May 05
Is it possible, if yes how..??

Comment: Probably a duplicate of [this SO-post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6981505/how-to-get-user-selected-date-format-in-android). The accepted answer to use `Settings.System.DATE_FORMAT` is promising.

Comment: yes..same..but still..my dbt is can we set that date format to Mon, 2014, May 05 if i select my settings date format to 2014/12/11

Answer (score 0):

Do not use SimpleDateFormat that way for solving your issue.
Use this:

```
DateFormat df = android.text.format.DateFormat.getTimeFormat(context);
```

This brings to you date format of your phone settings

And after this put your input date into:

```
DateUtils.format(...)
```

using `df` as pattern.

Comment: Is this what u meant DateFormat today = android.text.format.DateFormat.getTimeFormat(getActivity());
     DateUtils.formatDate(df, "E, MMM dd, yyyy"); but it doesnot display in that format..it shows only time

Comment: It is still showing in the format Mon, May 05, 2014

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DateUtils.formatDateTime(...)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html#formatDateTime%28android.content.Context,%20long,%20int%29) method to get a formatted date or a time according to the local conventions

Comment: dt = DateUtils.formatDate(df,"E, MMM dd, yyyy"); like this??