# Format date in Android

Tags: java, android, date, formatting

I have an Android app that parses a RSS feed. The "date" item returns the date in this format: "Mon, 16 Jun 2014 14:31:00 +0000". How can I convert this to the default device format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use simpleDateFormat

Something like:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("E, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss Z")
```

Comment: This, and to get the user's preferred date format, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6982154/1079597).

Answer (score 0):

First parse this to a Date object

```
String str = "Mon, 16 Jun 2014 14:31:00 +0000";
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("E, d, M yyyy H:m:s Z", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(str);
```